# Convert specific fields from a dataframe to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the below data:

```
Parent_Attribute    Attribute       Y/N for Modelling   Impute_Value    Type    Product     Description
age                     age             YES             Unknown         CAT     Multiple    ecohorts
bill_other          bill_other_m0       YES                 0           CAT     Multiple    Billing (other)
bill_other          bill_other_m1       YES                 0           CAT     Multiple    Billing (other)
bill_other          bill_other_m2       YES                 0           CAT     Multiple    Billing (other)
bill_other          bill_other_m3       YES                 0           CAT     Multiple    Billing (other)
bill_other          bill_other_m4       YES                 0           CAT     Multiple    Billing (other)
```

All these need to be stored in a dictionary where the attribute is the key and remaining column values as the values to that key:

```
attribute : ['parent_attribute,Y/N Modelling,Impute_Value,Type,Product,Description]
```

This has to be done for each row of the dataframe.

The completed dictionary will be looked like.

```
{                       
    age             :['age',"Yes","Unknown","CAT","Multiple","ecohorts"]                    
    bill_other_m0   :["bill_other","Yes",0,"CAT","Multiple","Billing(Other)"]                   
    bill_other_m1   :["bill_other","Yes",0,"CAT","Multiple","Billing(Other)"]                   
    bill_other_m2   :["bill_other","Yes",0,"CAT","Multiple","Billing(Other)"]                   
    bill_other_m3   :["bill_other","Yes",0,"CAT","Multiple","Billing(Other)"]                   
    bill_other_m4   :["bill_other","Yes",0,"CAT","Multiple","Billing(Other)"]                   
}
```

I went through `dataframe.to_dict` but it doesn't seem like only using that will help my purpose.
Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems need:

```
d = df.set_index('Attribute').T.to_dict('l')
```

Comment: `df.set_index('Attribute').T.to_dict('lazers')`  Remember the `'lazers'`

Comment: @piRSquared - `lazers` ? not `list` ?

Comment: For everyone else, the source checks the first character only.  Therefore you can pass any word that begins with `'l'`